# Cannot output spatial dataframe to .shp

Tags: r, gis, polygon, r-sf, convex-hull

I've used `gConvexHull()` to create a home range polygon that is classed as an `SP polygon`. In order to output as an `.shp` file, I converted it to a `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` and its new class is `"sf" "data.frame"`.

But when I try to output it using `writeOGR()`, it comes up with the error message:

```
Error in writeOGR(obj = HRDF, dsn = "C:/Users/RKirton/Documents/Data files",  : 
  inherits(obj, "Spatial") is not TRUE
```

I also tried `st_write()` and got this new error message:

```
Error in CPL_write_ogr(obj, dsn, layer, driver, as.character(dataset_options),  : 
  argument dsn, layer or driver not of length 1.
```

I'm fairly new to R and am unsure how to resolve these error messages.

Here is my code:

```
for(i in 1:length(unique(mydata$ID))) {
  hunt <- mydata[which(mydata$Season2 == "Hunt" & mydata$ID == 
  unique(mydata$ID)[i]), ]
  hunt_spdf <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords = cbind(hunt$X, hunt$Y), data = 
  hunt, proj4string = CRS("+init=epsg:32614"))
  HR = gConvexHull(hunt_spdf, byid = FALSE)
  plot(hunt_spdf)
  plot(HR, add = TRUE)
  HRDF = SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(HR, data = data.frame(IDs="Deer_HHR"))
  HRDF = st_as_sf(HR)
  HRDF
  HRDF$NEWCOL = "ID"
  HRDF
  st_write(obj = HRDF, dsn="C:/Users/RKirton/Documents/Data files", 
  layer=paste0('DeerHHR_', hunt$ID), driver="ESRI Shapefile")
  }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. I often find working with spatial data files/formats difficult too. What happens when you try to use `writeOGR()` with the original `sp polygon` object?

Comment: How did you convert it to a `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` ? Because it shouldn't have the class `sf`. Sounds like you've converted it to a Simple Feature object (sf), and so you can use `sf::st_write()` to output as a .shp file.

Comment: Hi Nate, When I tried to use writeORG with the original sp polygon it gave an error and said it was not an sf object...upon googling I discovered that to use writeOGR you need it to be either an sp polygon data frame or you need it to be an sf object.

Comment: Hi SymbolixAU, I will try this! I converted it using st_as_sf which is what my supervisor told me to do to make it an sf object so that I could write it out with st_write... it's highly possible I just got my wires crossed somewhere. I will post what I did in my question!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to tag someone in a comment you need to use the `@` symbol, as in `@SymbolixAU`, then they'll get notified.

Also, it's hard to find the errors in your code without having a reproducible example.

To try and help, here's a working example of creating an `sf` object from a `data.frame`, then finding the convex hull, then saving the .shp file(s) to a directory. If you want specific help you need to supply some data for others to work with.

This example is only using `sf` objects, not `sp`

```
library(sf)
library(sfheaders)

## An example data.frame
df <- data.frame(
  id = c( rep(1, 15), rep(2, 11))
  , x = rnorm(26)
  , y = rnorm(26)
)

sf <- sfheaders::sf_multipoint(obj = df, multipoint_id = "id", x = "x", y = "y")
sf <- sf::st_set_crs( sf, 32614 )
sf
# Simple feature collection with 2 features and 1 field
# geometry type:  MULTIPOINT
# dimension:      XY
# bbox:           xmin: 1 ymin: 1 xmax: 26 ymax: 26
# z_range:        zmin: NA zmax: NA
# m_range:        mmin: NA mmax: NA
# epsg (SRID):    32614
# proj4string:    +proj=utm +zone=14 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs
# id                       geometry
# 1  1 MULTIPOINT (1 26, 2 25, 3 2...
# 2  2 MULTIPOINT (16 11, 17 10, 1...

sf_hull <- sf::st_convex_hull( sf )
sf_hull

sf::st_write( obj = sf_hull, dsn = "~/Desktop/my_hull_dir/my_hull.shp")
```